# product_attribute_media.list gives Product not exists error in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php, soap

According to magento, this is the parameter list for the SOAP (v1) **product_attribute_media.list** call:

[image]
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductAttributeMedia/catalog_product_attribute_media.list.html

I have a numeric sku (e.g. 123456). So, when I call this api method, I get **Product not exists.** soap fault.

This is my code:

```
// Load existing images
$existingImages = $proxy->call(
    $sessionId,
    'catalog_product_attribute_media.list',
    (string)$SKU,
    $storeId,
    'sku'
);
```

Any ideas why this isn't working?

---

Before you ask; yes this product in **$SKU** (e.g. 123456) does exists in magento at the specified store id, I have already checked.

Answer (score 2):

Please try bellow my code

**Request Example SOAP V1**

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://test.com/api/soap/?wsdl'); // TODO : change url
$sessionId = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey'); // TODO : change login and pwd if necessary
$result = $client->call($sessionId, 'catalog_product_attribute_media.list', array('123456', '1','sku'));  //($sku, $store = null, $identifierType = null) 

var_dump($result);
```

**Request Example SOAP V2**

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://test.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'); // TODO : change url
$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey'); // TODO : change login and pwd if necessary

$result = $client->catalogProductAttributeMediaList($sessionId,'123456', '1','sku'); //($sku, $store = null, $identifierType = null) 
var_dump($result);
```